# Is it possible to run ANOVA using Mean differences?

Tags: anova, psychology

I'm wondering whether it is possible, and how to run an ANOVA on mean differences rather than on means. I want to run a 2*3 ANOVA on multiple comparisons. I'm wondering if I should treat each mean-diff as t-test outcomes, and if the tests come out non-significant to treat them as 0, or if I should just put the mean diff as-is for each condition.

Would pooling the variance between each pair of means be the appropriate way to get my SD's?

Thanks... Hope it's clear enough

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to run an ANOVA using differences between sub-groups as a response variable: e.g. you have two sets of populations (A and AA vs. B and BB) and you are interested in whether the difference (within-group variability of the difference) between the two sets is greater than the variability in differences within each set. So the new dataset is just x1=A1-AA1 etc. As long as the data satisfy distributional assumptions.

The second part is less clear: why do you need an external estimate of SD? It could be used as a covariate but it is not something you would do in a regular ANOVA, so we might be missing a specific context for this problem. It would be unconventional to treat them as t-test outcomes (and would confound it with repeated testing), actual differences are more informative.